# I am trying to communicate with a micro controller through a serial port . but my php script is giving me an error

Tags: php, mysql, arduino-uno

```
<?php
include "php_serial.class.php";

// Let's start the class
$serial = new phpSerial();

// First we must specify the device. This works on both Linux and Windows (if
// your Linux serial device is /dev/ttyS0 for COM1, etc.)
$serial->deviceSet("COM3");

// Set for 9600-8-N-1 (no flow control)
$serial->confBaudRate(9600); //Baud rate: 9600
$serial->confParity("none");  //Parity (this is the "N" in "8-N-1")
$serial->confCharacterLength(8); //Character length     (this is the "8" in "8-N-1")
$serial->confStopBits(1);  //Stop bits (this is the "1" in "8-N-1")
$serial->confFlowControl("none");

// Then we need to open it
$serial->deviceOpen();

// Read dataa
$read = $serial->readPort();

print "<pre>";
print_r($read);
print "</pre>";

// Print out the data
echo $read;
// print exec("echo 'r9g9b9' > /dev/ttyACM0");
print "RESPONSE(1): {$read}<br><br>";

// If you want to change the configuration, the device must be closed.
$serial->deviceClose();

// If you want to change the configuration, the device must be closed.
$serial->deviceClose();
?>
```

These are the errors

> Warning: Unable to set baud rate: in C:\xampp\htdocs\sensorsApp\php_serial.class.php on line 253
>
> Warning: Unable to set parity : in C:\xampp\htdocs\sensorsApp\php_serial.class.php on line 299
>
> Warning: Unable to set character length : in C:\xampp\htdocs\sensorsApp\php_serial.class.php on line 337
>
> Warning: Unable to set stop bit length : in C:\xampp\htdocs\sensorsApp\php_serial.class.php on line 375
>
> Fatal error: Unable to set flow control : in C:\xampp\htdocs\sensorsApp\php_serial.class.php on line 424

P.S how to save the received data into mysql database

Comment: Is $serial set? does $serial->deviceSet() have a return value to indicate success?

Comment: we have error if we do not specify the deviceSet()                             Warning: Missing argument 1 for phpSerial::deviceSet(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\sensorsApp\ser.php on line 9 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\sensorsApp\php_serial.class.php on line 96

Answer (score 0):

I assume your php_serial.class.php is this: https://code.google.com/p/php-serial/source/browse/trunk/php_serial.class.php?r=11

You should first do a `var_dump($serial)` before setting the baud rate to see if the initialization worked as intended. It should roughly contain the following:

```
_os = "windows";
_windevice = "COM3"
_device = "\\.\com3"
_dState = 1  // SERIAL_DEVICE_SET
```

If that worked so far, open a shell and see if manually setting the baud rate works:

```
mode COM3 BAUD=9600
```

Comment: i am using php_serial.class.php                                                             $serial->deviceSet("COM3");
   var_dump($serial->readPort()); is this the way to use var_dump  .I am new to php i have no idea         . at the end i should read data from serial port and save it to mysql DB so please can u suggest how to do this

Comment: I suggest you dump the contents of `$serial` before setting the baud rate. The statement for that would be `var_dump($serial)` as indicated by my answer.